# IE10 puts borders on link images, ignores CSS that fixes this issue for all other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

In dealing with the common "certain browsers put random borders on images inside links" issue, I typically use:

```
a img {
    border: 0;
}
```

That works for every browser except IE10, which persists in displaying the borders anyway.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Update: this issue doesn't occur on IE11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `style="border-style:none;"` but as inline-style of IMG element itself, not via CSS

Comment: That... is incredibly stupid. But, accepting your answer (as soon as I can) anyway, because it works and the stupidity is on Microsoft's part and not yours. Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully IE11 (which is "no longer Internet Explorer") will do better. There's always hope :)

Comment: The sad thing is, the CSS I cited in my question works in IE9 - so they actually went backwards in this release. Arguably with support for CSS3 things like text rotation, too.

Comment: @frank things must've changed in 4 years

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to only have a border when I explicitly declare one, so I use `* { border:none; }` and have never seen a rogue border.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the !important tag in your CSS?  Although, use of this is usually frowned upon in the Design community, but it's better than inline CSS style tags.

```
a img {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Tried it before asking. No effect.